# jquery + php - working with a JSON Array

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm creating a JSON arrary in Jquery and then sending it to php. In php I decode it but I get an error message. Below is an echo of the array that arrives in php and the error message. Note: I have only passed one item (to keep it smaller but in the further there would be more items in the array:

[image]

This is the current PHP code:

```
    print_r($_POST['cropData']);
    $cropData = json_decode($_POST['cropData']);
    print_r($cropData);
```

Also here is the jquery to generate the json array:

```
      jsonArray[thumbNum] = [{'src':val.attr('src')},
                            {'width':val.width()},
                            {'height':val.height()},
                            {'dataCX':val.attr('data-cx')},
                            {'dataCY':val.attr('data-cy')},
                            {'dataCW':val.attr('data-cw')},
                            {'dataCH':val.attr('data-ch')}
      ]
      thumbNum++;
    }

    $.post('scripts/php/join_processing.php', {
      'cropJoin': '1',
      'cropData': jsonArray},               
      function(data) {
```

Any advise on what I'm doing wrong here? I'm I sending an badly formed JSON array or not encoding it correctly?

thx

Comment: @donutdan4114: for what reason?

Comment: @zerkms: If you wanted to pass the JSON string through the POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the data-parameter of [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is "intelligent guess",
if you pass a JSON-string or a JS-object as data-parameter in jQuery.post(), it already posts it as an HTTP POST-array instead of a single json-string.
So, what you're receiving in php is already a usable array, so there's no need to decode it.

Btw; you could've easily seen this since you print_r the POST-variable and it obviously prints it as an array instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to decode it - it's already an array. So feel free to use it.

`$.post` passes it as an array, not as a json string.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JavaScript are different than arrays in PHP. You're probably not meaning to send a JS array, but a JS object (which will turn into a PHP array).

Try this code instead...

```
jsonArray[thumbNum] = {
  src: val.attr('src'),
  width: val.width(),
  height: val.height(),
  // ..
};
```

While will translate into a php object roughtly like this:

```
array(
  array(
    "src" => "",
    "width" => "",
    "height" => ""
  ), array(
    "src" => "",
    "width" => "",
    "height" => ""
  )
);
```

The other posters are *ALSO* right that you don't really need to `json_decode` everything, because $.post will convert it properly for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually creating a JSON array there. JSON is a string notation that can represent an array. You are actually creating a regular JavaScript array. `$.post` will properly pass that to your PHP script so `$_POST` will be populated correctly. `json_decode` is not needed at all.